# Swift 4: Making a request using URLSession and updating a global variable

Tags: json, multithreading, api, swift4, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am writing an app that gets predictions for busses by making an API call. In my case, there are 5 bus routes, which I would like to loop over in order to modify each API endpoint and then make a call. I am doing this in the viewdidload method through the following:

1. In the class, I have a global dictionary with the keys being route IDs
2. In viewdidload, I loop over this dictionary and call a method that returns a closure to update the dictionary:

   ```
   for routeid in prioritized_routes_with_stops.keys {
       let temp_val = prioritizedRoutesHelper (completion: {lst in
           self.prioritized_routes_with_stops[routeid] = lst
       }, routeid: routeid)//all I do here is set a value for the key routeid
       print (prioritized_routes_with_stops) //ISSUE
   ```
3. Here if that helper method, prioritizedRoutesHelper:

   ```
   func prioritizedRoutesHelper(completion: @escaping (((String, String), Int, Int)) -> (), routeid: String) {
       let formatted_url = "https://api.umd.io/v0/bus/routes/\(routeid)/arrivals/\(user_dict[routeid]!.0)"
       guard let url = URL(string: formatted_url) else {return}
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
           guard let data = data else {return}
           let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
           if (dataAsString?.contains("dirTitleBecauseNoPredictions"))!  == true{
               var temp = (("a", ""), 0, 0)//placeholder to see if update to "a"
               completion(temp)//ignore else case...
   ```

So, my question is as follows - why after the for loop in step 2, when I print my updated dictionary, no values have been updated. If, for example, I print the values in the dictionary in the closure, it prints the correct value, but when I print the global variable after looping through all of the routeids, it hasn't updated?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are making a GROUP of async requests, I suggest you to use a DispatchGroup, so, before  `for routeid in prioritized_routes_with_stops.keys {` add:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
```

then after that for add:

```
group.enter()
```

then inside your completion closure, before `self.prioritized_routes_with_stops[routeid] = lst` add :

```
group.leave()
```

finally after that for:

```
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print (prioritized_routes_with_stops)
}
```